# Refresh the menu items of Navigation Drawer when the back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, back-stack

I am using the Navigation Drawer to list Main menu items. One of the menu items being either New Quiz or Resume Quiz. If there is no existing quiz, then the menu item will show New Quiz (in the Navigation Drawer). After selecting the "New Quiz" option, the user will be presented with problems. When the back button is pressed, in the main menu, the Navigation Drawer still displays the New Quiz option as opposed to Resume Quiz. How do I invalidate the UI of the activity that is on the backstack?

Thank you.

Comment: I added the following code and it still does not work:

Comment: mMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_with_resume_quiz_option);
    ((ArrayAdapter<String>)mDrawerList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: the above is in the code when new quiz is selected. so that when the user returns back to the main activity, the navigation bar will show the resume quiz option.

Answer (score -1):

I addressed this by creating an ArrayList of menu items (as opposed to an array of String objects ). Then cleared the contents of the adapter and added the aforementioned array list in the adapter and called notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int counter = 0; counter < mMenuItems.length; counter++) {
    list.add(mMenuItems[counter]);
}
((ArrayAdapter<String>)mDrawerList.getAdapter()).clear();
((ArrayAdapter<String>)mDrawerList.getAdapter()).addAll(list);
((ArrayAdapter<String>)mDrawerList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers to understand even better.